# In Python I get an error that a global variable is not found, but in codeskupltor - the code works fine

Tags: python, global

I made a move from codeskulptor to a local installation of python on my computer. Therefore I need to use simplegui from simpleguitk. This basically works (except sound, but this is another issue, and I think not part of this question).
When I take this particular code that worked perfectly well in codeskulptor and transfer it to my local python (same version 2.7 just in case anyone feels this might be an issue) - I suddenly get that a global variable is not found. The code is long - but the issue comes in the function draw:

```
def draw(canvas):
    global time, started
    global lives, score
    global my_ship, rock_group, rock_rand_limit, missile_group, explosion_group

    # animiate background
    time += 1
    wtime = (time / 4) % WIDTH
    center = debris_info.get_center()
    size = debris_info.get_size()
    canvas.draw_image(nebula_image, nebula_info.get_center(), nebula_info.get_size(), [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2], [WIDTH, HEIGHT])
    canvas.draw_image(debris_image, center, size, (wtime - WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    canvas.draw_image(debris_image, center, size, (wtime + WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    # draw ship and sprites
    my_ship.draw(canvas)

    # update ship and sprites
    my_ship.update()

    if group_collide(rock_group, my_ship) == True:
        lives -= 1    

    score += group_group_collide(rock_group, missile_group)

    if lives == 0:
        started = False
        copy_of_rock_group = rock_group.copy()
        copy_of_missile_group = missile_group.copy()
        copy_of_explosion_group = explosion_group.copy()
        rock_group.difference_update(copy_of_rock_group)
        missile_group.difference_update(copy_of_missile_group)
        explosion_group.difference_update(copy_of_explosion_group)
        soundtrack.stop()
        timer.stop()
        soundtrack_timer.stop()
        new_game()
```

It says that the global variable: my_ship in the line:

# draw ship and sprites
  my_ship.draw(canvas)

is not defined. It also declares that a lot of other global variables are not defined. I must be doing something wrong but I can't find it.

If anyone can find the error - I'd be extremely happy to hear what I did wrong.

I am now including the whole program - and it's long, I'm sorry. It was an assignment in a courser course that I handed in several months ago. Since I did a search and found other people's solutions on the web, I assume that I can post this here. Please note that this will not run in codeskulptor because it is designed for simpleguitk and the way the sound works is different etc. So this is not an exact copy of my assignment - this is exactly the issue...
Thanks,
Jeff

```
# program template for Spaceship
# To be upgraded to RiceRocks for final mini-project
# (Keep in mind to check the template for RiceRocks for 
#  differences in the merge)
import simpleguitk as simplegui
import math
import random
import pygame

# globals for user interface
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FONT_SIZE = 20
LT_TEXT = 50
RT_TEXT = WIDTH - 100
TOP_TEXT = 30
BOT_TEXT = TOP_TEXT + 30
MAX_LIVES = 3
ZERO_SCORE = 0
score = ZERO_SCORE
lives = MAX_LIVES
time = 0
#time = 0.5

started = False

angle_update = 0.06
friction = 0.03
thrust_const = 0.25
missile_vel_factor = 10
missile_lifespan = 40
explosion_lifespan = 24
asteroid_crash_lifespan = 5

max_rocks = 6
ROCK_RAND_LIMIT_INIT = 0.95
rock_rand_limit = ROCK_RAND_LIMIT_INIT
ROCK_SHIP_BUFFER = 20


class ImageInfo:
    def __init__(self, center, size, radius = 0, lifespan = None, animated = False):
        self.center = center
        self.size = size
        self.radius = radius
        if lifespan:
            self.lifespan = lifespan
        else:
            self.lifespan = float('inf')
        self.animated = animated

    def get_center(self):
        return self.center

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def get_lifespan(self):
        return self.lifespan

    def get_animated(self):
        return self.animated


# art assets created by Kim Lathrop, may be freely re-used in non-commercial projects, please credit Kim

# debris images - debris1_brown.png, debris2_brown.png, debris3_brown.png, debris4_brown.png
#                 debris1_blue.png, debris2_blue.png, debris3_blue.png, debris4_blue.png, debris_blend.png
debris_info = ImageInfo([320, 240], [640, 480])
debris_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_blue.png")

# nebula images - nebula_brown.png, nebula_blue.png
nebula_info = ImageInfo([400, 300], [800, 600])
nebula_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.f2014.png")

# splash image
splash_info = ImageInfo([200, 150], [400, 300])
splash_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/splash.png")

# ship image
ship_info = ImageInfo([45, 45], [90, 90], 35)
ship_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/double_ship.png")

# missile image - shot1.png, shot2.png, shot3.png
#missile_info = ImageInfo([5,5], [10, 10], 3, 50) original value of lifespan is 50
missile_info = ImageInfo([5,5], [10, 10], 3, missile_lifespan)
missile_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/shot2.png")

# asteroid images - asteroid_blue.png, asteroid_brown.png, asteroid_blend.png
asteroid_info = ImageInfo([45, 45], [90, 90], 40)
asteroid_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png")
# asteroid-ship crash explosion
asteroid_crash_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blue.png")
asteroid_crash_info = ImageInfo([45, 45], [90, 90], 40, asteroid_crash_lifespan, False)
# animated explosion - explosion_orange.png, explosion_blue.png, explosion_blue2.png, explosion_alpha.png
explosion_info = ImageInfo([64, 64], [128, 128], 17, explosion_lifespan, True)
explosion_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/explosion_alpha.png")

pygame.mixer.init()

# sound assets purchased from sounddogs.com, please do not redistribute
#soundtrack = simplegui.load_sound("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/sounddogs/soundtrack.mp3")
soundtrack = pygame.mixer.Sound('c:\Users\jdanowit\Downloads\AnacondaPython\soundtrack.mp3')
#missile_sound = simplegui.load_sound("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/sounddogs/missile.mp3")
missile_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('c:\Users\jdanowit\Downloads\AnacondaPython\missile.mp3')
missile_sound.set_volume(.5)
#ship_thrust_sound = simplegui.load_sound("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/sounddogs/thrust.mp3")
ship_thrust_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('c:\Users\jdanowit\Downloads\AnacondaPython\thrust.mp3')
#explosion_sound = simplegui.load_sound("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/sounddogs/explosion.mp3")
explosion_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('c:\Users\jdanowit\Downloads\AnacondaPython\explosion.mp3')
##missile_sound = explosion_sound
# helper functions to handle transformations
def angle_to_vector(ang):
    return [math.cos(ang), math.sin(ang)]

def dist(p,q):
    return math.sqrt((p[0] - q[0]) ** 2+(p[1] - q[1]) ** 2)

def ranInRange(a,b):
    range_width = b - a
    return random.random() * range_width + a

# Ship class
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, angle, image, info):
        self.pos = [pos[0],pos[1]]
        self.vel = [vel[0],vel[1]]
        self.thrust = False
        self.thrust_amount = 0
        self.angle = angle
        self.angle_vel = 0
        self.image = image
        self.image_center = info.get_center()
        self.image_size = info.get_size()
        self.radius = info.get_radius()
        self.forward = angle_to_vector(self.angle)

    def draw(self,canvas):
        image_center = list(self.image_center);
        if(self.thrust == True):
            image_center[0] += self.image_size[0]

        canvas.draw_image(self.image, image_center, self.image_size, self.pos, self.image_size, self.angle)

    def update(self):     
        self.vel[0] *= (1 - friction)
        self.vel[1] *= (1 - friction)

        self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]

        self.pos[0] =  self.pos[0] % WIDTH
        self.pos[1] =  self.pos[1] % HEIGHT

        self.angle += self.angle_vel

        self.forward = angle_to_vector(self.angle)

        self.vel[0] += self.thrust_amount*self.forward[0]
        self.vel[1] += self.thrust_amount*self.forward[1]

    def update_angle_vel(self, delta):
        self.angle_vel += delta

    def stop_angle_vel(self):
        self.angle_vel = 0

    def update_thrust(self, doThrust): 
        self.thrust = doThrust
        if(self.thrust == True):
            #ship_thrust_sound.rewind()
            ship_thrust_sound.play()
            self.thrust_amount = thrust_const
        else:
            ship_thrust_sound.stop()
            self.thrust_amount = 0

    def shoot(self):
        #global a_missile
        global missle_group
        #calculate the position and velocity of the missile: missile_vel_factor
        missile_x = self.pos[0] + self.forward[0]*self.radius
        missile_y = self.pos[1] + self.forward[1]*self.radius
        missile_vx = self.vel[0] + self.forward[0]*missile_vel_factor
        missile_vy = self.vel[1] + self.forward[1]*missile_vel_factor
        missile_vel = [missile_vx, missile_vy]
        #print [cx + self.radius, cy]
        new_missile = Sprite([missile_x, missile_y], missile_vel, self.angle, 0, missile_image, missile_info, missile_sound)
        missile_group.add(new_missile)

    def get_position(self):
        return self.pos

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

# Sprite class
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, ang, ang_vel, image, info, sound = None):
        self.pos = [pos[0],pos[1]]
        self.vel = [vel[0],vel[1]]
        self.angle = ang
        self.angle_vel = ang_vel
        self.image = image
        self.image_center = info.get_center()
        self.image_size = info.get_size()
        self.radius = info.get_radius()
        self.lifespan = info.get_lifespan()
        self.animated = info.get_animated()
        self.age = 0
        if sound:
            #sound.rewind()
            sound.play()

    def draw(self, canvas):   
        if self.animated == False:
            canvas.draw_image(self.image, self.image_center, self.image_size, self.pos, self.image_size, self.angle)
        else:
            age = self.age
            im_cen_x = self.image_center[0] + age*self.image_size[0]
            im_cen_y = self.image_center[1]
            im_cen = [im_cen_x, im_cen_y]
            canvas.draw_image(explosion_image, im_cen, self.image_size, self.pos, self.image_size, self.angle)

    def update(self):
        self.angle += self.angle_vel

        self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
        self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] % WIDTH

        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]
        self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] % HEIGHT

        self.age += 1
        if self.age > self.lifespan:
            return True #remove me

        return False #keep me

    def get_position(self):
        return self.pos

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def collide(self, other_object):
        pos_other = other_object.get_position()
        rad_other = other_object.get_radius()

        object_distance = dist(self.pos, pos_other)

        if object_distance <= (rad_other + self.radius):
            return True

        return False

def new_game():
    global my_ship, rock_group, rock_rand_limit, missile_group, explosion_group
    global timer
    global soundtrack_timer

    my_ship = Ship([WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2], [0, 0], 0, ship_image, ship_info)
    rock_group = set([])
    missile_group = set([])
    explosion_group = set([])
    rock_rand_limit = ROCK_RAND_LIMIT_INIT

def process_sprite_group(current_set, canvas):
    remove_set = set([])
    for sprite in current_set:
        sprite.draw(canvas)
        remove_me = sprite.update()
        if remove_me == True:
            remove_set.add(sprite)

    current_set.difference_update(remove_set)    

def group_collide(group, other_object): 
    global explosion_group
    '''group is a set of sprites'''
    '''other_object is a single object like "ship" '''
    remove_set = set([])
    for element in group:
        if element.collide(other_object):
            if isinstance(other_object, Ship) == True:
                new_explosion = Sprite(element.get_position(), [0, 0], 0, 0, asteroid_crash_image, asteroid_crash_info, explosion_sound)
            else:    
                new_explosion = Sprite(element.get_position(), [0, 0], 0, 0, explosion_image, explosion_info, explosion_sound)

            explosion_group.add(new_explosion)
            remove_set.add(element)

    crashes = len(remove_set)
    group.difference_update(remove_set)

    if crashes > 0:
        return True

    return False

def group_group_collide(group1, group2):
    global explosion_group
    remove_set = set([])
    for g2 in group2:
        if group_collide(group1, g2) == True:
            #new_explosion = Sprite(g2.get_position(), [0, 0], 0, 0, explosion_image, explosion_info, explosion_sound)
            #explosion_group.add(new_explosion)
            remove_set.add(g2)

    number_of_collisions = len(remove_set)
    group2.difference_update(remove_set)

    return number_of_collisions


# mouseclick handlers that reset UI and conditions whether splash image is drawn
def click(pos):
    global started
    global score, lives
    global timer, soundtrack_timer
    if started == False:
        center = [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2]
        size = splash_info.get_size()
        inwidth = (center[0] - size[0] / 2) < pos[0] < (center[0] + size[0] / 2)
        inheight = (center[1] - size[1] / 2) < pos[1] < (center[1] + size[1] / 2)
        score = ZERO_SCORE
        lives = MAX_LIVES
        if (not started) and inwidth and inheight:
            started = True
            #soundtrack.rewind()
            soundtrack.play()
            timer.start()
            soundtrack_timer.start()

def draw(canvas):
    global time, started
    global lives, score
    global my_ship, rock_group, rock_rand_limit, missile_group, explosion_group

    # animiate background
    time += 1
    wtime = (time / 4) % WIDTH
    center = debris_info.get_center()
    size = debris_info.get_size()
    canvas.draw_image(nebula_image, nebula_info.get_center(), nebula_info.get_size(), [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2], [WIDTH, HEIGHT])
    canvas.draw_image(debris_image, center, size, (wtime - WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    canvas.draw_image(debris_image, center, size, (wtime + WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    # draw ship and sprites
    my_ship.draw(canvas)

    # update ship and sprites
    my_ship.update()

    if group_collide(rock_group, my_ship) == True:
        lives -= 1    

    score += group_group_collide(rock_group, missile_group)

    if lives == 0:
        started = False
        copy_of_rock_group = rock_group.copy()
        copy_of_missile_group = missile_group.copy()
        copy_of_explosion_group = explosion_group.copy()
        rock_group.difference_update(copy_of_rock_group)
        missile_group.difference_update(copy_of_missile_group)
        explosion_group.difference_update(copy_of_explosion_group)
        soundtrack.stop()
        timer.stop()
        soundtrack_timer.stop()
        new_game()

    process_sprite_group(rock_group, canvas)
    process_sprite_group(missile_group, canvas)
    process_sprite_group(explosion_group, canvas)

     # draw splash screen if not started
    if not started:
        canvas.draw_image(splash_image, splash_info.get_center(), 
                          splash_info.get_size(), [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2], 
                          splash_info.get_size())

    #lives and score
    canvas.draw_text("Lives",    [LT_TEXT, TOP_TEXT], FONT_SIZE, "white", "monospace")
    canvas.draw_text("Score",    [RT_TEXT, TOP_TEXT], FONT_SIZE, "white", "monospace")
    canvas.draw_text(str(lives), [LT_TEXT, BOT_TEXT], FONT_SIZE, "white", "monospace")
    canvas.draw_text(str(score), [RT_TEXT, BOT_TEXT], FONT_SIZE, "white", "monospace")

def keydown(key):
    global my_ship
    if started == True:
          if key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["up"]:    
             my_ship.update_thrust(True)

          if key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["left"]:
             my_ship.update_angle_vel(-angle_update)

          if key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["right"]:
             my_ship.update_angle_vel(angle_update)

          if key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["space"]:
             my_ship.shoot()

def keyup(key):   
      global my_ship
      if started == True:
          if key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["up"]:
              my_ship.update_thrust(False)

          if key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["left"] or key==simplegui.KEY_MAP["right"]: 
              my_ship.stop_angle_vel()

# timer handler that spawns a rock    
def rock_spawner():
    global rock_group, rock_rand_limit, my_ship

    if started == True:
        if len(rock_group) < max_rocks :
            #print "adding"
            pos_x = random.randint(0, WIDTH -1)
            pos_y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT-1)
            rock_ship_distance = dist(my_ship.get_position(), [pos_x, pos_y])
            if rock_ship_distance > (asteroid_info.get_radius() + my_ship.get_radius() + ROCK_SHIP_BUFFER):                          
                vel_x = ranInRange(-rock_rand_limit, rock_rand_limit)
                vel_y = ranInRange(-rock_rand_limit, rock_rand_limit)
                rock_rand_limit = min(rock_rand_limit + 0.001, 1.5)  
                print rock_rand_limit
                ang_vel = ranInRange(-0.05, 0.05)
                asteroid = Sprite([pos_x, pos_y], [vel_x, vel_y], 0, ang_vel, asteroid_image, asteroid_info)
                rock_group.add(asteroid)



def soundtrack_restart():
    print "restarting soundtrack"
    #soundtrack.rewind()
    soundtrack.play()

# initialize frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Asteroids", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

# register handlers
frame.set_keyup_handler(keyup)
frame.set_keydown_handler(keydown)
frame.set_mouseclick_handler(click)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

timer = simplegui.create_timer(1000.0, rock_spawner)
soundtrack_timer = simplegui.create_timer(180000.0, soundtrack_restart)

# get things rolling
frame.start()

# initialize game
new_game()
```

Comment: code snippet feature is for html code

Comment: StackOverflow is not a general debugging service: Code given to illustrate a problem should be the smallest possible thing that reproduces the problem at hand; any and all code _not_ related to the problem should be removed, and what's left should be tested that it runs and reproduces the problem as given. The code in this question is both insufficiently complete to run on its own, _and_ too large for code-read diagnosis. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and/or http://sscce.org/

Comment: please make the question succinct. Excursions into classes that you took last year do not help. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your last four lines of code -- `frame.start()` doesn't quit until your game is finished, but you have `new_game()` after that, so the globals are never initialized.

Comment: Thanks. For all those who made comments/voting me down - sorry for disappointing you. It took me a little while to  install and get my Python working on my computer. During that time I never posted and asked for help. Using codeskulptor, when you call start from the frame, you pass through somehow and, in my case, new_game is called. It seems that the way that Python works there and in my computer's install is different. I understood that there are differences that I did not quite understand so I posted. Ethan gracefully answered the question. Not everything works but now I have a head start.